# Can i define a default value for a HyperLink site column to include the item ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have the following column of type Hyperlink and I want its default value to include a url with the Id of the item, I tried to define the format inside the JSON but it did not work, as follow:

[image]

So can anyone advice how i can define a default value for a HyperLink site column to include the item ID?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set default value using JSON Formatting. To create a hyperlink using JSON Formatting, use below JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "Click to filter list view",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='https://abc.sharepoint.com/lists/test/allitems.aspx?FilterField1=MasterID&FilterValue1=' + [$ID]"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @johnGu, did you try this solution? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you create a Single line of text column and then convert this column into hyperlink formatting.

**Please the following steps:**

1.Create a Single line of text column in the list

[image]

2.Format this column

[image]

3.On the Formati column panel, click on **Advanced mode**

[image]

4.Use the below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MasterID&FilterValue1='+[$ID]"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Here is a similar case for your reference:

- [Can i define a default value for a HyperLink site column to include
  the item ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/550507/can-i-define-a-default-value-for-a-hyperlink-site.html)

========================== **Updated Answer** ======================

If you want to display the Hyperlink's URL and Alternative text in the Display Form.

**Please following steps:**

1.Create the following columns in the list

- TestID: Single line of text (TestID must be equal to ID)
- MasterID: Single line of text
- PrimaryName: Single line of text
- PrimaryURL: Calculated (calculation based on other columns)

**Formula:**

```
=CONCATENATE("https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MasterID&FilterValue1=",[TestID])
```

[image]

- TestLink: Single line of text

2.Column Formatting

[image]

3.Paste the following code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "[$PrimaryName]",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=[$PrimaryURL]"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

4.Hide Column

[image]

Comment: so if i follow your step , then the actual value of the column will not include the Id... it will only work if the users access the column from the list view? if this correct? this will not work inside the display form for example?

Comment: Hi john Gu. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!